# Showing images depending on Observables in angular 4

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I am getting data from an api with http get using Observables (Rxjs library) on Angular 4 project and I would like to show logo(png) depending on the data received from the API

For example when my object `[{{foo_icon}}]` received `0` I show a storm, when it received `1` I show a cloud and when it's `2` I want to show a sun

Here's is my code with what I'm trying since weeks now :

```
<p*ngFor="let user of userService.users | async"{{user.data.hosts.running.foo_icon}}</p> 

 <div *ngIf="cloud; then sun; else storm"></div>
<ng-template #sun><img class="foo-icon" src="./app/img/sun.png"/></ng-template>
<ng-template #cloud><img class="foo-icon" src="./app/img/cloud.png"/></ng-template>
<ng-template #storm><img class="foo-icon" src="./app/img/storm.png"/></ng-template>           
</div>
```

(userService received date from observable user)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ngIf directly on images.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
  <div *ngIf="user?.data.hosts.running.foo_icon as fooIcon">
     <img *ngIf="fooIcon === 'sun'" class="foo-icon" src="./app/img/sun.png"/>
     <img *ngIf="fooIcon === 'cloud'" class="foo-icon" src="./app/img/cloud.png"/>
     <img *ngIf="fooIcon === 'storm'" class="foo-icon" src="./app/img/storm.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can interpolate the ref of the icon in src attr

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
  <img *ngIf="user?.data.hosts.running.foo_icon as fooIcon" [src]="'./app/' + fooIcon + '.png'"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help 'guduf' but when I did that got an Error : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: It is because the value of `user` is `undefined`. You can pass a `?` operator. `*ngIf="user?.data.hosts.running.foo_icon as fooIcon"`

Comment: Thanks you are very cool....Got no error now with *ngIf="user?.data.hosts.running.foo_icon as fooIcon" but any image is going trough the browser..

Comment: you can try to do `<pre *ngIf="user?.data.hosts.running.foo_icon as fooIcon">{{ fooIcon }}</pre>` to be sure the `fooIcon` is a correct value.

Comment: When I do so got any error in the console but any data is comming trough the view but when I do                   <pre *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">{{user.data.apps.foo_icon}}</pre> I got the data comming up

Comment: My service where get the data from is setup like that:                            const usersURL = 'http://myback-end/weather/getFooReport.php';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  users: Observable<User[]>
    constructor (public http:Http) {
 this.users = http.get(usersURL)
                      .map(res => [res.json()]);

Comment: You have to wrap this blocks in *ngFor loop, if not `user` is never defined. I've edited my answer

Comment: Wooow it works many many thanks from Paris ! You remove me a big spine from the foot !

Comment: Avec plaisir ! (De la part d'un clermontois ;) )